# Cannot save files while debugging with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

When i am debugging a ASP.NET WebApp with Visual Studio 2013 i cannot save any files, so that means if a make a change to my HTML i have to stop debugging (i.e. also stop the site) then save then start debugging again to see my HTML changes.

If i detach VS2013 debugger i still cannot save files. Using Unlocker i see that `iisexpress.exe` have a lock on my files.

I do not have this issue with VS2012, where i can save my file and refresh and see the changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which SKU of the Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest update solved this issue.